# Django: set default behavior in include template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm looking to set a default behavior in a template to be included.

I have a problem with Django template system not allowing to set variables in template (I've read about the Django Philosophy, and I understand it).

Here is my example problem:

1. I want to include a template to render a newsfeed:

   ```
   template.html:
   ...
   {% include "_newsfeed.html" with slicing=":20" %}
   ...
   ```

   **I would like to not be forced to enter the `slicing` argument, and set a default behavior, let's say `":20"`**
2. In my `_newsfeed.html` , I would like to do (pseudo-code, it doesn't work):

   ```
   _newsfeed.html:
   ...
   {% if not slicing %}{% with slicing=":20" %}{% endif %}

   {% for content in newsfeed_content|slice:slicing %} 
       {# Display content #}
   {% endfor %}

   {% if not slicing %}{% endwith %}{% endif %}
   ```

Instead, I end up doing this below, that doesn't follow the DRY rule (and doesn't satisfy me!):

```
_newsfeed.html:
...
{% if not slicing %}{% with slicing=":20" %}

    {% for content in newsfeed_content|slice:slicing %} 
        {# Display content #}
    {% endfor %}

{% endwith %}{% else %}

    {% for content in newsfeed_content|slice:slicing %} 
        {# Display content #}
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
```

How should I do ?

Comment: Cant you set the default in code before you pass to the template?

Comment: The `_newsfeed.html` in included in many parts of the webapp, and had the default behavior previously (i.e. all current include tags are `{% include "_newsfeed.html" %}`). I would like to add the possibility to customize the slicing without having to modify all other parts of the webapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this via your template not your views file, you could create your own filter based on slice e.g.

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slice_filter

@register.filter("slice_default", is_safe=True)
def slice_filter_20(value, arg=":20"):
    return slice_filter(value, arg)
```